# What is the difference b/w using ` and not using in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

e.g.
query is

```
SELECT `username`, `uid`,`email` from profile  and `id`='0';
```

and

```
SELECT username, uid,email from profile  and id='0';
```

both will yeild same result.
so why we should use or not use ` in mysql query.

Comment: You use ` around the table or column name that is a MySQL reserved word; otherwise MySQL can't differentiate... e.g. `select id, desc from mytable` will cause problems because `desc` is a reserved word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name your columns anything if you use `` ` `` to delimit them. You could call it `timestamp`, `restrict` or any other keyword. Or you could call it `60000`. Or you could call it `domain of the flying spaghetti monster` if you really wanted.

```
SELECT `domain of the flying spaghetti monster` FROM `table`
```

has to be the weirdest select query I've seen!

Comment: You could call it timestamp anyway - but please don't; dotfsm is much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

The backtick and nonbacktick versions that you show both do the same thing.

The main reason one would use backticks is to escapse a MySQL reserved word or a column with a space in the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks will allow you use mysql reserved words as column names. Which is not a good idea to use anyways.

Example:

```
SELECT from, insert,delete from profile  and `id`='0'; will not work

SELECT `from`, `insert`,`delete` from profile  and `id`='0'; will work
```